# Bootstrap.php and autoloader

Tags: magento2

I've (as best I know how) written a small PHP front controller that allows me to quickly write scripts without having to worry too much about security, css etc as they are handled automaticially.

Annoyingly though, it looks like magento's bootstrap.php uses an autoloader and shutdown function as well, which leaves me with a conflict when including bootstrap.php in my scripts.

```
Message : Class file /home/customer/www/{{domain name}}/public_html/{{myapp folder}}/{{myapp subfolder}}/classes/zend\servicemanager\pluginmanagerinterface.php.php does not existMessage : Class file /home/customer/www/{{domain name}}/public_html/{{myapp folder}}/{{myapp subfolder}}/classes/paragonie_sodium_compat.php.php does not exist


Warning: register_shutdown_function(): Invalid shutdown callback '' passed in /home/customer/www/{{domain name}}/public_html/{{myapp folder}}/{{myapp subfolder}}/bootstrap.php on line 18
```

i've removed the domain name, application folder and subfolder for obvious reasons, but can't find a solution where I can run my own system with magento bootstrapped for certain functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after MUCH digging, it appears that the classes declared in the errors are being ignored by the Magento 2 autoloader, but the secondary autoloader of my own application is then trying to load them from it's own class path.

The classes don't appear to be required to run the bootstrap, so suppressing the paths in my own autoloader has bypassed the problem.

Additionally, the register_shutdown_function() error was because I wasn't declaring my function as a static method in an array ( [ classname, function ] )